# C++ Memory Allocation & Linked List Implementation

Tags: c++, malloc, linked-list, memset

I'm writing software to simulate the "first-fit" memory allocation schema.

Basically, I allocate a large X megabyte chunk of memory and subdivide it into blocks when chunks are requested according to the schema.

I'm using a linked list called "node" as a header for each block of memory (so that we can find the next block without tediously looping through every address value.

```
head_ptr = (char*) malloc(total_size + sizeof(node));

if(head_ptr == NULL) return -1; // Malloc Error .. :-(

node* head_node = new node; // Build block header

head_node->next = NULL;
head_node->previous = NULL;

// Header points to next block (which doesn't exist yet)
memset(head_ptr,head_node, sizeof(node));
```

`

But this last line returns:

```
 error: invalid conversion from 'node*' to 'int'
```

I understand why this is invalid.. but how can I place my node into the pointer location of my newly allocated memory?

Comment: Yes it is, my question involves syntax help more so than theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memset(void* memory, int value, size_t size)
```

So, it's not to copy the `head_node` into `head_ptr` (you are thinking of `memcpy`),
it's for initializing memory (clearing to 0, marking as freed, etc...).

In this case, you could simply cast the `head_ptr` to a `node*`:

```
node* head_node = (node*)head_ptr;
```

And now you don't have to `delete head_node`, or copy the values to `head_ptr` at all.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution.  You are correct, I was confusing the purpose of memset with memcpy and I see how that could have also worked.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs.  [`memset`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/memset.html) takes an int (but interpreted as a `unsigned char`) as a second parameter.  This specifies the value to set the first `n` bytes, where `n` is the third parameter, of the memory region to.

You could use [`memcpy`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html), which will copy one region of memory to another.  Try:

```
memcpy(head_ptr, head_node, sizeof(node));
```

EDIT: Another alternative is to use a pointer cast of head_ptr to set the previous and next values, as suggested by Simon.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to construct your node object into the memory allocated and pointed to by head_ptr. If you need the node constructor to be called, you do this via the [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) operator like so:

```
node* head_node = new(head_ptr) node;
```

If you do need to make sure that the destructor is called as well, then you have to call delete manually:

```
head_node->~node();
```

Comment: If he's using `placement new` then he should also use `placement delete` -- can make no assumptions without the definition of `node`.  Chances are `placement new` can be skipped altogether as it's probably just a dumb `struct`.

Comment: Placement new would be `new (head_ptr) node`, you are constructing a `node` with `head_ptr` as an argument.

Comment: @Vlad: Nitpicking, but C++ guarantees placement delete is a noop. The inverse of `new (ptr) T` is `ptr->~T()`.

Comment: @Simon, the reason why I brought it up is that we do not know whether or not his `node` is a dumb struct or not, i.e. whether his destructor actually does anything (for all we know, he could have a `std::string` member in his `node` which has to be destructed.) :)

Comment: @Vlad: Which is why it's important to know that `delete (ptr) T` does nothing. You have to call the destructor manually.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign pointers like that. Second argument is `int` to be repeted.

From `memset(3)`:

```
SYNOPSIS
     #include <string.h>

     void *
     memset(void *b, int c, size_t len);

DESCRIPTION
     The memset() function writes len bytes of value c (converted to
     an unsigned char) to the byte string b.

RETURN VALUES
     The memset() function returns its first argument.
```